# Reading 1000s of XML documents with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, enthought

I'm trying to read a bunch of xml files and do stuff to them. The first thing I want to do is rename them based on a number that's inside the file.

You can see a sample of the data [here](http://storage.googleapis.com/patents/grant_full_text/2015/ipg150106.zip)<sup>Warning this will initiate a download of a 108MB zip file!</sup>. That's a huge xml file with thousands of smaller xml files inside it.  I've broken those out into individual files.  I want to rename the files based on a number inside (part of preprocessing).  I have the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # To get everything
import os

def rename_xml_files(directory):
    xml_files = [xml_file for xml_file in os.listdir(directory) ]

    for filename in xml_files:
        filename = filename.strip()
        full_filename = directory + "/" +filename
        print (full_filename)
        f = open(full_filename, "r")
        xml = f.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
        del xml
        del soup
        f.close()
```

If I comment out the "soup =" and "del" lines, it works perfectly.  If I add the "soup = ..." line, it will work for a moment and then it will eventually crap out - it just crashes the python kernel. I'm using Enthought Canopy, but I've tried it running from the command line and it craps out there, too.

I thought, perhaps, it was not deallocating the space for the variable "soup" so I tried adding the "del" commands.  Same problem.

Any thoughts on how to circumvent this?  I'm not stuck on BS.  If there's a better way of doing this, I would love it, but I need a little sample code.

Comment: Can you show an example XML file being parsed?

Comment: If you have access to more than a single core, you may get some insights from https://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `cElementTree.parse()` from Python's standard `xml` library instead of BeautifulSoup. 'Soup is great for parsing normal web pages, but cElementTree is blazing fast.

Like this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as cET

# ...

def rename_xml_files(directory):
    xml_files = [xml_file for xml_file in os.listdir(directory) ]

    for filename in xml_files:
        filename = filename.strip()
        full_filename = directory + "/" +filename
        print(full_filename)
        parsed = cET.parse(full_filename)
        del parsed
```

If your XML formatted correctly this should parse it. If your machine is still unable to handle all that data in memory, you should look into [streaming](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.reader.html) the XML.

Comment: I tried using that and then went back to BS, because I couldn't figure out the exact calls to make it give me what I wanted.

Comment: `parsed.getroot().getchildren()` should get you started. You can read the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: This has been very helpful advice. The samples you provided worked perfectly and the further suggested reading helped me extend what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would not separate that file out into many small files and then process them some more, I would process them all in one go.

I would just use a `streaming` api XML parser and parse the master file, get the name and write out the sub-files once with the correct name.

There is no need for BeautifulSoup which is primarily designed to handle HTML and uses a document model instead of a streaming parser.

There is no need for what you are doing to build an entire DOM just to get a single element all at once.