# parse xml files in subdirectories using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have more than 5000 XML files in multiple sub directories named f1, f2, f3, f4,...
Each folder contains more than 200 files. At the moment I want to extract all the files using BeautifulSoup only as I have already tried lxml, elemetTree and minidom but am struggling to get it done through BeautifulSoup.

I can extract single file in sub directory but not able to get all the files through BeautifulSoup.

I have checked the below posts:

[XML parsing in Python using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785831/xml-parsing-in-python-using-beautifulsoup) (Extract Single File)

[Parsing all XML files in directory and all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38211588/parsing-all-xml-files-in-directory-and-all-subdirectories) (This is minidom)

[Reading 1000s of XML documents with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267755/reading-1000s-of-xml-documents-with-beautifulsoup) (Unable to get the files through this post)

Here is the code which I have written to extract a single file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = BeautifulSoup(open('./Folder/SubFolder1/file1.XML'),'lxml-xml') 

print(file.prettify())
```

When I try to get all files in all folders I am using the below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = BeautifulSoup('//Folder/*/*.XML','lxml-xml') 

print(file.prettify())
```

Then I am only getting XML Version and nothing else. I know that I have to use a for loop and am not sure how to use it in order to parse all the files through the loop.

I know that it will be very very slow but for the sake of learning I want to use beautifulsoup to parse all the files, or if for loop is not recommended then will be grateful if I can get a better solution but only in beautifulsoup only.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you do need to loop through the files, as you had already thought:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path

for filepath in Path('./Folder').glob('*/*.XML'):
    with filepath.open() as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f,'lxml-xml')
    print(soup.prettify())
```

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is just one approach to handling paths, on a higher level using objects. You could achieve the same with [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and string paths.

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob.glob` to find the XML documents:

```
import glob

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for filename in glob.glob('//Folder/*/*.XML'):
    content = BeautifulSoup(filename, 'lxml-xml')
    print(content.prettify())
```

*note*: don't shadow the builtin function/class `file`.

Read the [BeautifulSoup Quick Start](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)